# unselect css selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm running a wordpress site with a [jquery fadein script](http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/4940/). I have a general selector that selects all the text and images on my website (globally) and adds a fadein to it.

How do i deselect the blog/single post pages? I don't want the selector to target: ".single-post" pages.

The selector i am using is

`$("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img").addClass("hideme");`

I know basic jQuery & PHP, hopefully there is a simple option!

Comment: post your loop code.

Comment: You could simply use the [body_class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) selector and add a `if ( !$("body").hasClass("single-post") ) { -your-code-here- }` around your current selector.